# Scheduling java programs using oozie

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, oozie

I have a java program which accepts a XML input file (as an argument) and processes it. The java program reads files from hdfs and writes to hdfs.

The program uses cascading application platform to perform operations on hadoop.

My question is, can I schedule this program using oozie? I tried executing some sample java programs using oozie. They are always launched in a single mapper. Hence, I am not able to read the XML file.

I also tried implementing a shell action, however, I am still not able to get it working.

I tried a executing a simple HelloWorld program through shell action. The HelloWorld program accepts an argument and prints it on the console. [image: Shell Action Details]

I am getting the following error:[image: Error Details]

Comment: Is the HelloWorld.jar in hdfs?

Comment: @RamananR, yes, it is in hdfs.